# Sql Server sysprocesses query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following query which runs fine on all of my sql server 2005/2008 databases

```
SELECT sysprocesses.spid
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
```

However for one of my databases it give me a binding error on the spid column (cannot bind multipart identifier).

I've check the compatibility mode of the db and it's set to 2005 so I'm sure this isn't the problem but can't figure out what else to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT s.spid
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses s
```

However, `master.dbo.sysprocesses` and its compatibility view `sys.sysprocesses` are deprecated, so use this instead:

```
select session_id from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

see: [Mapping System Tables to System Views (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
select spid from sys.sysprocesses
```

instead.  `dbo.sysproceses` is deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: This does indeed fix the problem in this particular script.  However I'd really like to know why this would fail to run on some configurations as it seems to be affecting other scripts too.

Comment: It sounds to me like someone with sysadmin privileges somehow accidentally borked the definition of your dbo.sysprocesses view at some point...